# Is it possible to click on a report record to open relevant form in Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a report with details of jobs/tasks, and also a form which contributes the majority of the data towards that report.  Given that a report is a nice way of looking at the larger picture of the data, and a form is the best way of editing data, I would like to be able to click on a row, and have it open up the relevant record in the form view.

Does anyone know how to do this through VBA?  In my mind it should be possible, though my knowledge of objects in Access is limited.

**Update**

I've implemented the following code for my report:

```
Private Sub Edit_Click()

  Dim EntityName As String
  Dim DocName As String

  DocName = "Entity: Overview"

  strWhere = "[Entity Name]='" & Entity & "'"
  DoCmd.OpenForm DocName, acNormal, , EntityName

End Sub
```

It successfully opens the correct form, and it also grabs the correct entity name, however it isn't filtering properly.  I can't see what the issue is with the code.

Comment: Do you mean `DoCmd.OpenForm DocName, acNormal, , strWhere` ?

Comment: @Remou Ah, yes I do!  Don't know how I missed that!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Edit_Click()` procedure, you have `EntityName` as the *WhereCondition* parameter to `OpenForm`.

```
  DoCmd.OpenForm DocName, acNormal, , EntityName
```

However, you haven't assigned anything to `EntityName`, so it's an empty string.  I think you should use `strWhere` as the *WhereCondition*.

```
Private Sub Edit_Click()
  Dim strWhere As String
  Dim DocName As String

  DocName = "Entity: Overview"
  strWhere = "[Entity Name]='" & Me.Entity & "'"
  DoCmd.OpenForm DocName, acNormal, , strWhere
End Sub
```

I assumed `Entity` is the name of a control, and that's where you get a value to build `strWhere`.  If there is no control in the report by the name of `Entity`, then the code won't work even if there is an `Entity` in the original query.

Comment: I feel a little bit special!  Can't believe I missed that!  Thank you all for your help with this, it's working great now.  This is great, my database is really moving along with all this VB code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an *On Click* event in the *Detail* section of the report, then add something like this in the VBA handler:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", acNormal, "", "ID=" & ID.Text
```

(where *MyForm* is the target form, and *ID* is a hidden or visible control in your report that identifies the current record).

Comment: Thanks for this - your point that the ID has to be a hidden or visible control in my report is very true.  Even though my report is strictly based off an ID (located in the original query), when it wasn't included in the report my code didn't work.  I added it in as an invisible control, and it works well now.

Answer (score 1):

You say report, but you should not be using a report but a continuous form or datasheet. You can then add events to any of the controls on any line, and add a **double-click** event, if you do not want to drive your users insane. You could also add a command button if that would be clearer to your users, or format the "link" textbox to underline. The record opened by the action shown by @dbaseman will open which even record has the focus (current record). And that will lead you to discover what you can and can't do with a continuous form :D

Comment: you're like my database mentor! Thanks for always responding to my Q's. Anyway, can you get continuous forms to look as good as reports? Because I quite like the look of my reports. Not at work now, I'll try these things tomorrow. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: You can get a continuous form to look quite nice, but not, perhaps, as nice as a report. However, they are much more functional. I think perhaps you need to look at forms in general in more detail. For example, the form/subform set up is very useful indeed.

Comment: alright I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Ultimately functionality is prime, it's just nice to have a good appearance as well. I have incorporated some continuous forms as subforms in some of my forms, they're great. Most my forms now have them as I have a lot of 1-M relationships.

Comment: I had a bit of a go with the continuous forms, but I wasn't happy with the overall design.  I like the idea of starting off on a truly read-only report, then clicking on a button which leads to editing the report.  Also it's seems to be almost working - see the update in my original question.