# How to get checkbox to function on Access 2010 report?

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox, ms-access-2010

I’m developing a DB application via MS Access 2010.
I have added an unbound, binary checkbox to a **report** with the purpose that a user can choose one of two record sources (queries), for two variations of the report.
The checkbox `Control Source` property is blank and the `Triple State` is set to `No`.

However, upon opening the report, 
the checkbox is permanently greyed out, no matter haw many times it is clicked!
Also, upon each *single* click on the checkbox, `my_checkbox_Click()` fires *twice* with its value toggling between `Null` and `True`!
The Null value seems to be interpreted as `False` which might be OK if the event didn't double-fire on each single click.

How do I get my checkbox to both *appear* properly -- as a *binary* checkbox, toggling between yes and no -- and *function* correctly, firing `_Click()` only *once* per click?
If it's a known issue with no solution, which is the best button type as a workaround?

My code:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Report_Load"
    Me.my_chk.Value = False
    set_data_source
End Sub

Private Sub my_chk_Click()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "my_chk_Click"
    set_data_source
End Sub

Private Sub set_data_source()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "set_data_source"
    Debug.Print "Me.my_chk.Value", Me.my_chk.Value
    Debug.Print "Me.my_chk.ControlSource ", Me.my_chk.ControlSource
    Debug.Print "Me.my_chk.TripleState ", Me.my_chk.TripleState
    Me.RecordSource = IIf(Me.my_chk.Value, "my_yes_qry", "my_no_qry")
    Me.Requery
    Debug.Print "Me.RecordSource", Me.RecordSource
End Sub
```

Immediate window:

```
Report_Load

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value         False
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_no_qry

' click once on checkbox

my_chk_Click

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value         Null
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_no_qry

my_chk_Click

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value         -1 
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_yes_qry

' click once on checkbox

my_chk_Click

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value         Null
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_no_qry

my_chk_Click

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value         -1 
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_yes_qry
```

The only good news is that the `Requery` after a `RecordSource` changes does correctly (if all-too-briefly) affect the data.

Another thing, even though my checkbox doesn't have an `AfterUpdate` listed under `Events`, if I replace the above `my_checkbox_Click()` handler with

```
Private Sub my_chk_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "my_chk_AfterUpdate"
    set_data_source
End Sub
```

I get

```
Report_Load

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value   False
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_no_qry

' click once on checkbox

my_chk_AfterUpdate

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value   -1 
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_yes_qry

' click once on checkbox

my_chk_AfterUpdate

set_data_source
Me.my_chk.Value   -1 
Me.my_chk.ControlSource         
Me.my_chk.TripleState           False
Me.RecordSource             my_yes_qry
```

which, as you can see, doesn't work either because now, even though `AfterUpdate` fires once per click, the checkbox value doesn't change!

Over at [access-programmers.co.uk/forums](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=219087)
there was a suggestion (regarding a form, not a report) to use fancy coding

```
Nz(Me.my_chk = True, False)
```

which I tried but it had no difference in outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure a checkbox on a **report** can be checked as it can in a form?  I'm not!  But an interesting possibility can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324121/122139).

In the case of a form, it's grayed out because it is unbound and the value isn't set.  The solution is to make a form variable and set to that.  When the form is loaded, set the variable to False and set the checkbox to the variable.  In the `AfterUpdate()` event of the checkbox, use the value of the control to set the variable.  Then run `set_data_source`.  You will probably want to run `set_data_source` also when the form loads.

```
Option Explicit

Dim booSourceUsual as boolean

Private Sub MyForm_Load()
    booSourceUsual = False
    Me!my_chk.Value = booSourceUsual
    Call set_data_source
End Sub

Private Sub my_chk_AfterUpdate()
    booSourceUsual = Me!my_chk.Value
    Call set_data_source
End Sub
```

Comment: My report's checkbox never changes from grey. I don't know if that's a universal truth, why it is, or how i was supposed to know.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work (for a report).

Comment: "...how i was supposed to know..." -- hey, I'm learning from your post that a report can have click events.  Always something to learn and never enough ways to know.

Comment: The typical approach is to make your decision from a form.  Unless the post I cited at top of my answer leads to something, I think that's what you have to do.  And even if it does, I think I'd go with the form!

Comment: I think you're suggesting using a form instead of a report, but i'm using a report because of its easy sub-totaling functionality. If a report cannot handle user-interaction, then i think i'll just use two forms (for the two queries) instead of one.

Comment: I see.  It's true subtotals are very simple with a report, not so with a form.